# Chrome and overflow:hidden issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, overflow

In my javascript I use the jquery `animate()` function to slide tweets automatically.

Code:

```
function movefeeds() {
   var element = jQuery("#Feeds");
   var position = element.position();

   if(position.left == 2000){
      element.css("left", "500px");
   } 

   element.animate({ "left": "-=500px" }, "slow");   
}
```

In every browser to code does exactly what it must do: sliding. But in Chrome it is not sliding always, it is sliding half the time. And even if it slides, `left` gets really bad values (ie. 584.2132312 instead of 500, 1000 etc.)

Any suggestion would be appreciated :-)

EDIT: Looks like a css issue: `chrome` (from version 11) seems to have some trouble with `overflow:hidden`

EDIT 2: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001158/problem-with-overflowauto-and-chrome)

Comment: An alternate approach might be to use the [`hide & slide`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide) feature of jQuery UI.

Comment: Cant reproduce that in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6HkyN/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Could not find any solution for using `overflow:hidden` in chrome. 
So I removed the `overflow` from my css and put some div's with z-index over the tweets to hide them.</strike>

Found my solution in this: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001158/problem-with-overflowauto-and-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

This may seem like an odd answer, but it's consistent with what I've seen happen in chrome before with animations:

Are you including your javascript after your CSS?  Depending on how your page is set up, I've seen Chrome flake out as it's trying to run javascript before CSS styles are loaded, so your animation won't work because it doesn't have the element's `position` attribute loaded yet.

Comment: Javascript is included after all css includes. `position` gets a value when debugging

Comment: First of all check out the "position" value first by insert alert(position); before the IF statement...then you will know the true value of "position".

Comment: @BorisD position is exactly what is supposed to be. But the chrome browser doesn't show my tweet at that position